# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "+": syntax error sqlite3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET hp+60, SET money+50')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "+": syntax error
```

помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

В SQL у выражения `UPDATE` общий синтаксис такой:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

См. [SQL UPDATE Statement](https://%20https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_update.asp)

При этом слева от каждого `=` - название изменяемой колонки, справа от него - новое значение в этой колонке.

У вас во-первых нет `=` - вы просто пытаетесь "плюсовать" число к имени колонки; во-вторых - два раза написан `SET`.

Чтобы работало (`hp` во всех строках увеличилось на 60, `money` - на 50), выражение должно быть таким

```sql
UPDATE users SET hp = hp + 60, money = money + 50
```